# How to disable editor

Tags: django, django-forms, django-tinymce

I use django-tinymce to input formatted text. I need to disable whole field in form and all editor buttons but can't find how. If anyone has idea about how it can be done, please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use HTML `read only` attribute. Here's a trick to do that via widget:

```
myform.fields['status'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

Comment: I apply this thing to all fields in my form and it doesn't work on the tinymce field only.